# How to bind a function with sub-observables to an observable array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have following ViewModel:

```
var Order =  function(data) {
  this.fruits = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Fruis, function(item) { return item; }));
  this.vegetables = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Vegetables, function(item) { return item; }));
};
```

I need to define some sub-properties and sub-observables bound to the specific instance, and some common methods for fruits and vegetables,:

```
var Items =  function(data, type) {
  var self = this;
  self.type = type;
  self.choice = ko.observable(-1);
  self.choice.select = ko.computed(function(){
    var id = self.choice();
    // do stuff
  });
  self.choice.remove = function() {
    var id = self.choice.peek();
    // do stuff
  };
  self.add = function(code) {
    //do stuff
    self.choice(id);
  };
};
```

Which is the right way to bind the function containing my set of methods and sub-observables, so that i can use the methods as follows:

```
orderViewModel.fruits.add("apples");
orderViewModel.fruits.add("bananas");
orderViewModel.fruits.choice(0);
orderViewModel.fruits.choice.remove();

console.log(ko.tpJSON(orderViewModel));
// prints: {fruits: [bananas], vegetables: []};
```

I think there is no need to use *extenders*, as the properties and methods aren't generic, and don't need to be common to all observables.

I tried by returning an observable array from my Item function, but i wasn't able to get this to work, as sub-properties and sub-observables have been lost. How can i bind `Items` to my observable arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you might not want to create an extender, what you're doing here *is* extending an observable array...

If you don't want to register an extender, you can create a small helper function to create an `observableArray` and add some methods and properties to it before you return.

In the example below you can see some example code. Some important advice:

- If you use this approach, I'd suggest not overwriting the default methods in `observableArray`. E.g.: `remove` takes an item by default; you want it to work with an external `choice` index... It's best to pick a different name so you keep supporting both.
- If you end up using the extension a lot, it might be worth it to create a clean viewmodel that stores the observable array internally. You can define a `toArray` method for exporting to a plain array.

```js
var obsCollection = function(initialItems) {
  
  var items = ko.observableArray(initialItems);
  
  items.choice = ko.observable(-1);
  items.add = items.push;
  
  var ogRemove = items.remove.bind(items);
  
  // I'd rename this to "deleteChoice"
  items.remove = function() {
    var index = items.choice();
    ogRemove(items()[index]);
    // Reset choice to -1 here?
  };
  
  
  return items;
};

var fruits = obsCollection(["Apple"]);

log(fruits);
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.choice(0);
fruits.remove();
log(fruits);
fruits.remove();
fruits.add("Mango");
fruits.add("Lemon");
log(fruits);

function log(d) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ko.unwrap(d)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

**Edit to clarify the (lack of) use of `this`:**

Since we don't use the `new` keyword, there's no real need to use `this`. Internally, the `observableArray` creates a `new` instance, but our only way of referring to this instance is through `items`. When detaching prototype methods from the array, we need to make sure we call them with the right context, by either `bind` or `.call(items)` (or `apply`).

If you want the code to look like a "class", you can either do: `var self = items;` and continue with the `self` keyword, or rewrite it to use the `new` keyword (last bullet point in my answer).

```js
var myArray = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);

try {
  // Reference the function without binding `this`:
  var removeFromMyArray = myArray.remove;

  // Internally, the observableArray.prototype.remove method
  // uses `this` to refer to itself. By the time we call it,
  // `this` will refer to `window`, resulting in an error.
  removeFromMyArray(2);
} catch(err) {
  console.log("ERROR:", err.message);
  console.log(myArray());
}


// By binding to the array, we ensure that the function reference
// is always called in the right context.
var boundRemoveFromMyArray = myArray.remove.bind(myArray);
boundRemoveFromMyArray(2);
console.log(myArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: THX, adjusted the mistake with `remove`, so it is now `choice.remove` Could you please kindly update your answer?

Comment: I'm near to get it, i believe inside methods, `items` shall be `this`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... When extending, it is important to keep track of your `this` context, but if you define all your methods in the closure of `obsCollection`, you can just refer to the observable array instance in `items`. Note that you can use `bind` to fixate `this`.

Comment: If you want `type` to be exposed to the outside, I'd put it in `items` (since that's what you return). You can then reference it via `items.type`, no need to use `this`. If `type` is a "private" variable, you can pass it as an argument which makes it available in `items`'s closure. You can *not* use `var self = this` since we're not using the `new` keyword and the `this` context when we enter `obsCollection` can be anything depending on the context of the caller.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! I accept your answer because it lead me to a working solution, and i can't upvote more than once, but IMHO i think it doesn't fully addresses the usage of `this`inside the custom methods attached to the observable..

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added some more text concerning the `this` stuff, but I'm afraid I can't help you much more with that. If there's a specific problem you could maybe post a new question. If you link it here, I'll make sure I take a look :)